# Wordpress site, add baners, ads, outside of main block

Tags: css, wordpress

I have a wordpress site. The main body of it is alling to center, where all content goes. See image below
[image]

So white space is what I call main body (I'm not a web developer)
What I want to do is to add some baners, etc.. on the sides (on blue spaces).
Can I somehow achieve it using css or something else?

Thanks

Comment: CSS is just for styling, you would have to add the HTML for the banners to those spaces and you could define the styling with CSS.

Comment: Thanks, but I really won't be able to do it with my knowledge of web programming. If you could provide more detailed information how to achieve it, it would be very useful